# URL and Query management Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

Ok so while back I asked question [Beginner ASP.net question handling url link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986598/beginner-asp-net-question-handling-url-link)

I wanted to handle case like this www.blah.com/blah.aspx?day=12&flow=true
I got my answer string r_flag = Request.QueryString["day"];

Then what I did is placed a code in Page_Load()

that basically takes these parameters and if they are not NULL, meaning that they were part of URL.

I filter results based on these parameters.

It works GREAT, happy times.... Except it does not work anymore once you try to go to the link using some other filter.
I have drop down box that allows you to select filters. 
I have a button that once clicked should update these selections.

The problem is that Page_Load is called prior to Button_Clicked function and therefore I stay on the same page.

Any ideas how to handle this case.

Once again in case above was confusing.
So I can control behavior of my website by using URL, which I parse in Page_Load()
and using controls that are on the page.

If there is no query in URL it works great (controls) if there is it overrides controls.
Essentially I am trying to find a way how to ignore parsing of url when requests comes from clicking Generate button on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can put your querystring parsing code into IsPostBack control if Generate button is the control that only postbacks at your page.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string r_flag = Request.QueryString["day"];
}
```

As an alternative way, at client side you can set a hidden field whenever user clicks the Generate button, then you can get it's value to determine if the user clicked the Generate button and then put your logic there.

Comment: awesome it kind causes another problem but thats the one I know how to fix. Thanks